# How to speed up my loop for a list with 90k items?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, loops, foreach

I have this grouping:

```
var data = weatherDataList.Items
                .GroupBy(w => new { w.Temperature, w.RelativeHumidity })
                .ToList();
```

The `weatherDataList` contains 90k items. Data has about 26k items.

I've tried several loops: `foreach`, `for` and `for` with Duff's Device implementation. All three takes about 2 minutes and 40 seconds to complete.

The next thing I did was replacing the `foreach` with `Parallel.Foreach`. This took 50 seconds to complete. A huge improvement.

Here's the implementation:

```
var list = new ConcurrentBag<TemperatureHumidityScatterItem>();

Parallel.ForEach(data, groupedItem =>
            {
                var item = new TemperatureHumidityScatterItem();
                var totalInGroup = groupedItem.Count();

                item.Humidity = groupedItem.Key.RelativeHumidity;
                item.Temperature = groupedItem.Key.Temperature;
                item.YearCount = totalInGroup / weatherDataList.TotalDifferentYears;
                item.BadCell = IsBadCell(groupedItem.Key.Temperature, groupedItem.Key.RelativeHumidity);

                list.Add(item);
            });
```

Although 50 seconds is a great improvement, I am wondering if this can be done faster. Is there something I can do to get more performance?

PS: Unfortunately I can't show the `IsBadCell` implementation, but I can tell that it is doing purely mathemathical calculations (divisions, summing, etc.) and it takes <1ms to complete.

EDIT:
Here's the implementation of `WeatherDataList`:

```
public class WeatherDataList
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<WeatherData> _weatherData;

    public WeatherDataList(IEnumerable<WeatherData> weatherData)
    {
        _weatherData = weatherData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the lowest and highest year in the weather data and subtracts them: 2020 - 2013 = return 7
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int TotalDifferentYears => _weatherData.GroupBy(w => w.TimestampUtc.Year).Count();

    /// <summary>
    /// Count all the days in the weather collection
    /// </summary>
    public int TotalDifferentDays => _weatherData.GroupBy(w => w.TimestampUtc.Day).Count();

    public int SunriseHour => 6;//_weatherData
        //.OrderBy(w => w.TimestampUtc)
        //.FirstOrDefault(w => w.IsDay()).TimestampUtc.Hour;

    public int DayLength => 13; //_weatherData.Count(w => w.IsDay());

    public IEnumerable<WeatherData> Items => _weatherData;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the total days for the specified month over all the years in the weather collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="monthNo"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int GetTotalDaysForMonth(int monthNo)
    {
        var years = _weatherData.GroupBy(w => w.TimestampUtc.Year).Select(g => g.Key);
        return years.Sum(year => DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthNo));

    }

    public WeatherDataList GetWeatherDataForMonth(int monthNo) => 
        _weatherData.Where(d => d.TimestampUtc.Month == monthNo).ToWeatherDataList();

    public WeatherDataList GetWeatherDataForOneDay(DateTime day)
    {
        return new WeatherDataList(_weatherData.Where(i =>
            i.TimestampUtc.Day == day.Day &&
            i.TimestampUtc.Month == day.Month &&
            i.TimestampUtc.Year == day.Year));
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216802/discussion-on-question-by-martijn-how-to-speed-up-my-loop-for-a-list-with-90k-it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Maybe not an answer, but to much example for a comment)

```
/// <returns></returns>
public int TotalDifferentYears => _weatherData.GroupBy(w =>w.TimestampUtc.Year).Count();
```

So, for 90.000 Iterations, you are Grouping and counting 90.000 times. You could improve that by storing the count, once it has been done as _weatherData can't change:

```
private int? _totalDifferentYears = null;

public int TotalDifferentYears {
    get 
      {
         if (_totalDifferentYears != null) 
            return _totalDifferentYears;

         _totalDifferentYears = _weatherData.GroupBy(w =>w.TimestampUtc.Year).Count();
         return _totalDifferentYears;
      }
    }
```

or even better: Do that during object construction and use a simple property for the result:

```
    private int _totalDifferentYears = 0;
    public int TotalDifferentYears { get {return _totalDifferentYears } }

    public WeatherDataList(IEnumerable<WeatherData> weatherData)

    {
        _weatherData = weatherData;
        _totalDifferentYears = _weatherData.GroupBy(w =>w.TimestampUtc.Year).Count();
    }
```

Comment: This was definitely the solution. It went from 45 secs to 9ms. Thanks for catching this!

Answer (score 2):

So the first thing i can see is that the _weatherdata in WeatherdataList is not a List but an Enumerable. Can you do a do a .ToList() in the constructor of weatherdatalist? because if you dont do that the reason for it taking so long could be that the data is not loaded where it is coming from and that can take time. So please cast _weatherdata to a list and then post your timings again.

In general i can see that your classmethods are reusing the Enumerable multiple times. This can be cause for bugs too.